# jQuery AutoComplete not populating ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to populate an AutoComplete in my Web App. The list is populated from a datatable. For some reason, I can't get it to show in the autocomplete. I know I'm getting results from the query because I can use a messagebox to view them. In this example, I'm limiting the results to 5.

Client-Side Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddToMonitoring.Default" %>

<head runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=txtAutoComplete.ClientID%>").autocomplete('AutoCompleteHandler.ashx');
    });
</head>
<body>
    <div id="inputDIV" style="font-size: x-large; font-family: Calibri; 
        position: relative; top: 25px; left: 25px; height: 638px; width: 1239px;">                
        Asset Name: <asp:TextBox id="txtAutoComplete" runat="server" />
    </div> 
</body>
```

Here is the handler page:

```
public class AutoCompleteHandler : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        dsCIInfoTableAdapters.BMC_CORE_BMC_ComputerSystemTableAdapter serverTableAdapter1;
        serverTableAdapter1 = new dsCIInfoTableAdapters.BMC_CORE_BMC_ComputerSystemTableAdapter();

        dsCIInfo.BMC_CORE_BMC_ComputerSystemDataTable newServerTable;
        newServerTable = serverTableAdapter1.GetData();


        var query = (from row in newServerTable.AsEnumerable()
                     where row.Field<string>("Item") == "Server"
                     select row.Field<string>("Name")).Distinct().Take(5);

        var queryArray = query.ToArray();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (string row in queryArray)
        {
            context.Response.Write(sb.Append(row).Append(Environment.NewLine));
        }

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any script errors in your chosen browsers development tools (F12 in most)

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use the StringBuilder?  Seems odd.  Instead of `context.Response.Write(sb.Append(row).Append(Environment.NewLine));` would you try `context.Response.Write(row + Environment.NewLine);`  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to nix the handler page, instead used a hiddenElement

Client-Side

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tags = eval($("#<%=txtHiddenAutoComplete.ClientID%>").val());
    $("#<%=txtAutoComplete.ClientID%>").autocomplete({ source: tags });
})
```

Moved the query to the Page_Load function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dsCIInfoTableAdapters.BMC_CORE_BMC_ComputerSystemTableAdapter serverTableAdapter1;
        serverTableAdapter1 = new dsCIInfoTableAdapters.BMC_CORE_BMC_ComputerSystemTableAdapter();

        dsCIInfo.BMC_CORE_BMC_ComputerSystemDataTable newServerTable;
        newServerTable = serverTableAdapter1.GetData();


        var query = (from row in newServerTable.AsEnumerable()
                     where row.Field<string>("Item") == "Server"
                     select row.Field<string>("Name")).Distinct();

        var queryArray = query.ToArray();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("[");
        foreach (string row in queryArray)
        {
            sb.Append("\"").Append(row).Append("\",");
        }

        sb.Append("]");
        sb.Replace(",]", "]");
        txtHiddenAutoComplete.Value = sb.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQUery autocomplete expects a javascript definition of parameters.

You are passing it a server handler.

I guess you must be receiving a javascript error. Check console.

I usually define autocomplete with an AJAX call to a server method where I load the data from database and return it to the autocomplete plugin.

I'm not used to work with aspforms, but I'm pretty sure you're not going on the right direction.

Check documentation for further info:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

change last four line in your asp.net handler as

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string row in queryArray)
    {
        sb.Append(row).Append(Environment.NewLine);
    }

    context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

and add the missing closing script block.

and add this also

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```